# ReSharper doesn't see my Machine.Specification tests

Tags: resharper, xunit.net, mspec

I'm having a problem getting ReSharper to see the Machine.Specification "tests" I've written.

The specs run in the ConsoleRunner from mSpec. When I try to "Run Unit Tests" in ReSharper, I get a message: "No tests found in file." The specs don't show the test markers.

I created a folder in the ReSharper /bin/ folder and put the proper .dlls there. The mSpec plug in appears in ReSharper.

What might I be missing?

Also, I'm using xUnit.NET if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ReSharper runner do not take nested context classes into account. Instead of nesting context classes:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Specs
    {
        public class when_something_happens
        {
            Because of = () => {};
            It should_do_something = () => {};
        }
    }
}
```

Author contexts that are not nested, i.e. root classes inside a namespace:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class when_something_happens
    {
        Because of = () => {};
        It should_do_something = () => {};
    }
}
```

ReSharper's green-and-yellow test icons do appear if all of the conditions are met:

- class is public
- class is not abstract
- class is not nested
- has >= 1 specification field (`It`),
  or has >= 1 behavior field
  (`Behaves_like<>`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; and the help via Twitter.

Comment: +1 Yikes. Is there any other way?!?!?! So, I stumbled upon what a ReSharper unit test report looks like and am impressed, and I also had the same issue as the author. Thing is, I have over 200 classes (over 2500 'Specs' in MSpec), they inherit abstracted logic/helpers and such. Yes, it can all be refactored around. But I have a concern around the Contextes being shared (more refactoring!) and how the MSpec report will order things.

Comment: I wrote a version of the ReSharper runner that supports nested contexts - we're still considering putting this in the official master.
http://github.com/agross/machine.specifications/tree/nestedtypes

Still, IMHO namespaces are the preferred method to structure contexts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have good integration of MSpec with Visual Studio and ReSharper install MSpec using installer which is available here: http://marcinobel.com/index.php/mspec-bdd-installer/

Answer (score 0):

Had also the same problem with "No tests found in file" when try to use ReSharper and XUnit.net together. However I could see my tests in Test Explorer window and was able to run them from there.